# Change directory index based on domain url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In a 3 domain structure, for example main.com eng.com and esp.com
All share the same files but the html content is in different languages.
Instead of replicating and maintaining 3 set of files, i would like to handle the domains in the same application folder, with 3 "index" files.
The user will go to /en.html or /es.html depending of the domain, its just for the domain root.
Is like a conditional directory index.

Is this possible? I was thinking of something like (where main.com still uses /index.html):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eng\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://eng.com/en.html [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^esp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://esp.com/es.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work as expected, but solved it with PHP, feedback would be appreciated:

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?esource\.mx$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?esource\.com\.mx$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.esc-nube\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://esc-nube.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?esource\.us$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.esc-cloud\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://esc-cloud.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.esourcecapital\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://esourcecapital.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if ($domain == "esourcecapital.com") {
    $filename = "esc.html";
} if ($domain == "esc-nube.com") {
    $filename = "es.html";
} if ($domain == "esc-cloud.com") {
    $filename = "en.html";
}

$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
?>
```

Any tips for speed?

Comment: Just read about file_get_contents(), that supposedly is more optimized.